# How to generate JSON array from dynamically added list items in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am new in Angular 2. I have an auto-complete text input which suggest categories of item on search. When I click on any of suggested category, It appends in a list `category-tags` as a new list-item (using JQuery).

I want to post these categories in list-items into database, for that I want to make a JSON array as "categories".

**auto-complete input code:**

```
<h6>Add category</h6>
        <div class="col-lg-12 padding0">
            <input [formControl]="term" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Category Name" id="product-category-input">
            <div class="catsuggestions col-lg-12 padding0">
                <ul>
                    <li (click)="addCategory()" *ngFor="let item of items | async"><a href="#!" data-catid="item.categoryId">{{item.categoryName}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Items adds in this list**

```
<ul class="category-tags"></ul>
```

Please help me to know how can I make JSON array on dynamically added list items. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a json pipe for such things. It should work almost automatically.